# I want to use multiple popovers with buttons in the Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, io

When using Popover with a button in SwiftUI, I want to popover with multiple buttons as shown below, but as it is, only the upper button
I can't get a popover. What if you want to popover both separately?

```
struct MySelection: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        var text = ""
    }
    
    struct PopoverTest: View {
        @State var selected: MySelection?
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack (spacing: 88) {
                // First Button
                Button(action: {
                    selected = MySelection(text: "Popover1")
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "stopwatch")
                })
                // Second Button
                Button(action: {
                    selected = MySelection(text: "Popover2")
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                })
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            .popover(item: $selected) { selection in
                Text(selection.text).font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: really? Here, even if you press "globe", Popover will appear on the "stopwatch" button. I want Popover to appear on the "globe" button even if I press "globe". If it is normal, is it an environmental problem?

Comment: ahhh ... you didn't mention you run it on iPad or macOS, right? (on iPhone its rendered as a sheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking it over, the better way might be to create a custom "button with popover" view that can be used anywhere:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 88) {
            
            // First Button
            ButtonWithPopover(image: "stopwatch",
                              item: MySelection(text: "Popover1"))
            
            // Second Button
            ButtonWithPopover(image: "globe",
                              item: MySelection(text: "Popover2"))
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}


struct ButtonWithPopover: View {
    
    let image: String
    let item: MySelection
    
    @State var selected: MySelection?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            selected = item
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: image)
        })
        .popover(item: $selected) { selection in
            Text(selection.text).font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After all this method seems to be good. At first, I was thinking about the method below, but I was in trouble because the number of buttons was changed by the user's operation method.
I will try this method as a basis. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it seems you have to introduce 2 `selected` vars. The optional selected can hand over different values to the popover, but if it is triggered from different subviews, SwiftUI doesn't know where to anchor the popover to.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected1: MySelection?
    @State var selected2: MySelection?

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 88) {
            
            // First Button
            Button(action: {
                selected1 = MySelection(text: "Popover1")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "stopwatch")
            })
            .popover(item: $selected1) { selection in
                Text(selection.text).font(.largeTitle)
            }
            
            // Second Button
            Button(action: {
                selected2 = MySelection(text: "Popover2")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
            })
            .popover(item: $selected2) { selection in
                Text(selection.text).font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```